# How to get "fixedLength: true" to show up in a migration script using annotations instead of fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations, ef-fluent-api

I am trying to convert some fluent API code in to data annotation code however there is one thing I am stuck on. What does [`StringPropertyConfiguration.IsFixedLength()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.stringpropertyconfiguration.isfixedlength%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) translate to?

Here is a example of one of my fixed length fields.

```
this.Property(t => t.ChangeType)
    .IsRequired()
    .IsFixedLength()
    .HasMaxLength(1);
```

I tried to translate it to

```
[Required, StringLength(1, MinimumLength = 1)]
public string ChangeType { get; set; }
```

however the first example produces the following in the migration script

```
ChangeType = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 1, fixedLength: true),
```

and the second example produces

```
ChangeType = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 1),
```

What do I need to do to get `fixedLength: true` to automatically show up in a migration script?